# Typescript setInterval error: XYZ is already declared in the upper scope

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint

I am encountering a curious error where I create a handler function and attempt to set the current ref to the state's value plus 1:

```
const useTimer = () => {
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
  const counterRef = useRef(null);

  const handleStart = () => {
      counterRef.current = setInterval(() => {
          setSeconds((**seconds**) => seconds + 1);
      }, 1000);
  };

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleStart}>Start</button>
  )
}
```

eslint is now kicking on that `'seconds' is already declared in the upper scope on line 8 column 10.` and it's caused by the `seconds` parameter of `setSeconds` (highlighted with ** in the snippet above).

Question 1: Am I missing something programmatically or is this really just a false eslint error?

Question 2: When I remove `null` from `useRef`, `counterRef.current` is underlined with the error `Type 'Timeout' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.` How do I initialize `useRef` correctly when `setInterval` is going to be the future value?

**EDIT:** Found [this answer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) in the react docs:

> If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can pass a function to setState. The function will receive the previous value, and return an updated value.

Makes more sense why `no-shadow` kicked on. Thanks to all commenters.

Comment: About `seconds`, it's just [ESLint's `no-shadow` rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-shadow). Just rename the parameter in its small scope to anything that's not already declared in the upper scope. e.g. `sec` would work.

Comment: That said, you should [only ask a single question at a time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371617/1218980) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re. Question 1: this warning is valid. You are declaring two **different** variables named `seconds` in two different places, creating ambiguity in certain scopes.

```
const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
//     ^^^^^^^

setSeconds((seconds) => seconds + 1);
//          ^^^^^^^
```

I would fix this by renaming:

```
setSeconds((prevSeconds) => prevSeconds + 1);
```

Re. Question 2: type your ref as follows:

```
// If using NodeJS setInterval:
const counterRef = useRef<NodeJS.Timeout|null>(null);

// If using window.setInterval (ie. in a browser):
const counterRef = useRef<number|null>(null);
```

Edit: To support response to comment - `setInterval` and `setTimeout` return a `number` in a web browser.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. Can you elaborate on Question 2, why does number work as the setInterval return type? Used it in the browser and the return type I am seeing when hovering over setInterval is `NodeJS.Timeout`

Comment: Your IDE is showing you typings for NodeJS setTimeout/setInterval. To be explicit, use `window.setInterval` to ensure your IDE gives you the correct typings for the web. The return type of `setInterval` and `setTimeout` in a browser is indeed `number`. This number is a sort of "id" that your browser uses to uniquely identify your interval. You can re-use this number with `window.clearInterval`, for example, to stop it.

Comment: @HJW and you should reuse this number to stop the interval when the component unmounts.

Comment: @EmileBergeron to stop the interval I did `clearInterval(counterRef.current)`. Is that correct?

Comment: @HJW yes, should be fine!